# how to access methods from another class from specflow hooks

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I have a base class which has all the common methods like login,logout.
I want to use these common methods inside my hooks ,how can it be done.

hooks and baseclass are located in different namespace and i have imported the naspace of baseclass inside hooks.
my Hooks

```
    [BeforeScenario("tag")]
                public void TestSetupAdminUser()
                {
                    string BrowserName = Configapp["Connection:Browser"];
                    IWebDriver driver = 
                   DriverFactory.InitDriver(BrowserName);

                    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Configapp["Connection:Url"]);
                    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                    if (??.IsLogoutVisible()
```

I would like to access  IsLogoutVisible() method from my base class here ,how can I do that.?? is for the question how to access the method.

if (??.IsLogoutVisible() && propertyName != "abc")

My Base class has only 1 static member so context injection of base class inside hooks constructor doesnot work .

```
private   static  IWebDriver driver = DriverFactory.Driver;
```

Comment: Where is `IsLogoutVisible` defined? That isn't clear in your question. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills Edited the question with more details

Comment: Show full code - all classes that are involved

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for context injection. Could you please check out the below video. If that doesn't work then look for the dependency injection in c# may be that could help you :)
 https://youtu.be/-PtPcWMtIGc

Comment: any injection is giving me an error "The type initializer for 'baseclass' threw an exception.) (The type initializer for 'baseclass' threw an exception.) which I beleive happens as my base class has a static member as mentioned in question

Comment: Are you not planning for the parallel execution? Because you will definitely face an issue while working with static webdriver in parallel execution. If parallel execution is not in scope then that is great. We need to check for how we can do the serialization and deserialization of an object in C#. I can easily do that in Java but I am not sure about C#

Comment: I believe that this will help you. 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/serializing-objects-in-C-Sharp/